# Connect Playstation Console via VPN to the internet PLEASE HELP

Tags: 12.04, vpn, ps3

I have a VPN connection to the internet with my PC and want to connect my Playstation 3 to the internet. I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC. How do I do that?

Can I use Internet Connection Sharing? I only have one LAN spot in my PC. Do I need to buy another one? Does ICS work with VPN? Are there other options.

I can ONLY use VPN to connect to the internet.